# After applying DELETE and UPDATE cascade not able to DELETE/UPDATE from parent table

Tags: mysql

I have applied both DELETE CASCADE and UPDATE CASCADE constraints on child table.

```
alter table table_product_categories add constraint fk_product_id1 foreign key (product_id) references table_products (product_id) on delete cascade;

alter table table_product_categories add constraint fk_product_id2 foreign key (product_id) references table_products (product_id) on update cascade;
```

Now when trying to delete in parent table:

```
DELETE FROM table_products WHERE `table_products`.`product_id` = 1819
```

Getting this error:

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table_product_categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_product_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `table_products` (`product_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

When trying to update parent table

```
UPDATE  `wokoshop`.`table_products` SET  `product_id` =  '1' WHERE `table_products`.`product_id` =1819
```

Getting this error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wokoshop`.`table_product_categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_product_id2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `table_products` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

What is the reason for errors and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but you don't need to create two different constraints. Create one constraint with both `cascade` options.

Comment: does the order of cascade will matter?

Comment: Have a sneeky Peek [at the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) Quick while nobody is looking. Its a radical idea but sometimes nothing else will do

Comment: @Barmar, It worded.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating two constraints, use a single constraint with both `CASCADE` options:

```
alter table table_product_categories 
    add constraint fk_product_id1 foreign key (product_id) 
    references table_products (product_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade;
```